# RabbitMQ 2 Queues

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, priority-queue

Saw similar questions but different expected answers.  My question is can I can create a consumer to focus on a single queue until it empties then switch to the other queue, until new work is sent to their main queue?

For example: 1 queue contains large amount of work to be processed in longer time frame and its own dedicated consumers (3 for instance).  The 2nd queue receives much less work that requires less processing.  If the consumers for the 2nd queue complete their work can I make it so they switch to the first queue until their queue receives more work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this question, it's important to keep in mind that there is a difference between a "consumer" in the canonical sense vs. a "consumer" in the RabbitMQ sense.

**A RabbitMQ Consumer** is a contrivance of the protocol - basically, it is a designation that the channel/connection would like to have messages pushed to it, under a designated consumer tag. In this sense, it is merely a notification to the broker to immediately send messages.

In the canonical sense, **a message consumer** is any piece of code that processes messages.

So, the answer to  your question is "yes, go ahead and write your program to do that."  You have control over the canonical consumer code. It is up to your software to determine what to do with a message that arrives from a queue.

Now, if you're wondering if RabbitMQ can re-subscribe a consumer to a different queue, the answer is "that's not how it works." In RabbitMQ, a consumer is simply a response to a request to subscribe to a queue - it is a "consumer tag" object. The ongoing nature of the subscription is tied to the channel/connection pair.

**What should you do?** While your code doesn't specify any particular coding language, in my opinion, you're off-track by even asking this question.  Subscribe to both queues. If there is nothing for the worker to do, I think the computer would be perfectly happy with that. If you're worried about a particularly busy queue issuing too much work, you can use a number of techniques to throttle messages coming into that consumer. One popular technique is [prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#prefetch).

Comment: Good point on the clarification.  One the what I should do I'm confused why language matters (java fyi), but sounds like RabbitMQ itself is not capable of this configuration.  I can programmatically switch the consumers when one queue empties to the other queue.  I was hoping there was a built in way to consume from multiple.  There does seem to be some confusion bc you brought up prefetch though.  Not worried about overloading the consumers.  Just trying to be efficient.

Comment: and thanks for the answer, it seems 'No' is basically right

Comment: I think you may be over-architecting a bit... just dump the messages into your processor. I personally perfer to segregate queues by message type, so it would logically not make sense to have multiple different queues with the same type of message.

Comment: It moreover has to do with SLA of the messages.  One queue has a large quantity with unlimited SLA, while the other is much smaller with a near immediate SLA.

Comment: There's nothing stopping your other worker from doing a basic.get on that other queue.

Comment: Ahh that works perfectly!  Didnt know about basicGet

Comment: So I have figured out that you can add multiple queues to a channel and consumer.  And you can add priority as an argument.  But it doesn't seem to consider emptying one queue before pulling from the 2nd.

Comment: That's correct, it's going to do a round-robin on you. What people don't realize about how the protocol works under the hood is that a `basic.get` and a `basic.deliver` (what the consumer uses) are essentially the same network packet. The difference is which side initiates it. A consumer pushes messages, a `get` pulls messages. Your case describes an example when you want to pull.